# FLTK Setting width of display area of slider value

Tags: c++, fltk

I was wondering how to change the width of the area responsible for showing the current value of a Fl_Hor_Value_Slider. The thing is, I want to be able to select a year (that's 4 digits) and the space on the side of the slider is not enough to display the year number correctly.

[image]

I've looked through the docs and tried the following functions:

```
slider_size()
maximum()
minimum()
range()
```

But they don't seem do do what I want.
I feel as though I've missed something obvious.
Any ideas?

Comment: I have sort of solved the problem XD
I simply decreased the textsize() and got the number to fit in.
It's not the requested solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the size is hardcoded to 35 for horizontal or 25 for vertical.  You need to modify Fl_Value_Slider.cxx.  In the routine draw, it has

```
if (horizontal()) {
  bww = 35; sxx += 35; sww -= 35;
} else {
  syy += 25; bhh = 25; shh -= 25;
}
```

This is based on a textsize_ of 10.  If you change the text size, then it needs to go up based on the text size.  Something like

```
if (horizontal()) {
   int width = textsize() * 3 + 5;
   bww = width; sxx += width; sww -= width;
} else {
   int height = textsize() * 2 + 5;
   syy += height; bhh = height; shh -= height;
}
```

Then rebuild the fltk library.  Either keep this patch or send it to FLTK and check whenever you get an update from FLTK.  To test

```
  Fl_Hor_Value_Slider* o = new Fl_Hor_Value_Slider(10, 50, 250, 50, "");
  o->tooltip("Value Slider");
  o->selection_color((Fl_Color)1);
  o->textsize(25);
  o->value(2000)
  o->range(2000, 2099);
  o->precision(0);
```

**Edit**

Alternatively, create your own Hor_Value_Slider based on Fl_Hor_Value_Slider and override the draw method.

Comment: @cup Thanks for this good answer. I created a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/fltk/fltk/issues/285) for this question and added your code suggestions. Note: this doesn't mean that it will be implemented soon, but it's there as a reminder.

Answer (score 0):

For the record: meanwhile FLTK 1.4.0 (not yet released) got new methods for sliders: `value_width(int)` and `value_height(int)`, respectively. These methods let you set the width of the value field on horizontal and the height of the value field on vertical sliders.

Documentation can be found here:
https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.4/classFl__Value__Slider.html